# Codeigniter return object with loop for variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

```
$campaigns = $this->campaign->get_all();

foreach ($campaigns as $campaign){}
    for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++) { 
        echo $campaign->call_center_.$i;
    }
}
```

I want to return `call_center_1` to `call_center_5` object, how to do that properly, my above code doesn't work.

it always return an error message:

```
 Undefined property: stdClass::$call_center_
```

**EDIT**

```
var_dump($campaigns);
```

return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [campaignId] => 8
            [call_center_1] => 021123123
            [call_center_2] => 
            [call_center_3] => 
            [call_center_4] => 
            [call_center_5] =>
        )

)
```

Comment: print_r($campaigns) and show your result

Comment: try `->{"call_center_$i"}`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$campaigns = $this->campaign->get_all();
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign){
  for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++) { 
    echo $campaign->{'call_center_'.$i};
  }
}
```

i have tried like:-

```
$link = new stdClass();
$link->id = 1;
$link->campaignId = 1;
$link->call_center_1 = '021123123';
$link->call_center_2 = '';
$link->call_center_3 = '';
$campaigns = array($link);
print_r($campaigns);
foreach ($campaigns as $campaign){
  for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++) { 
    echo $campaign->{'call_center_'.$i};
  }
}
```

Comment: still error sir  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: check now let me know?

Comment: try now i have checked my end

Comment: the above code is give the value of call_center_1 for each record

Comment: see my answer i give solution for that

Comment: edit this line `print_r($arr);` unless you'll get `Undefined variable: arr` @RakeshSharma

Answer (score 0):

```
$campaigns = $this->campaign->get_all();

foreach ($campaigns as $key => $campaign){
     echo 'for '.$key.'-----'; 
     for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++) { 
        echo $campaign->call_center_.$i;
        echo '<br>';
     }

   }
```

Try this it will work for you.

Comment: i thing you need to vardump your $campaigns first.